# pandas median of count of a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

```
g  | val
1     a
1     ''
2     b
2     ''
2     c
3    ''
```

I have a df.groupby('g') and I want to select the median of the count of the non empty vals in each group. How to do that in pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you need ? (Count will not count the `NaN` , this why we replace the '' to `np.nan`)

```
df.val=df.val.replace('',np.nan)
df
Out[243]: 
   g  val
0  1    a
1  1  NaN
2  2    b
3  2  NaN
4  2    c
5  3  NaN

df.groupby('g').val.count().median()
Out[245]: 1.0
```

Filter before groupby

```
df[df.val.isin(['','somethingealse'])].groupby('g').val.count().median()
```

Comment: I like the other solution because it is more generic but thanks :)

Comment: @mkmostafa  interesting ... you can simple test the speed on your side .

Comment: is there a reason to prefer one to the other? also is there a way to count non empty values?

Comment: @mkmostafa if you data set is large , then apply will take much longer time than the way I am using

Comment: but there is no other way to extend this to filter other non empty values?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is by using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function:

```
# inside apply, we can filter values
df.groupby('g')['val'].apply(lambda x: x[x!= ''].count()).median()
Out[2]: 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just slice your frame excluding the empty values in the `val` column, then use `groupby` and count the median.

```
df[df['val']!=''].groupby('g').val.count().median()
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty strings evaluate to `False` in a boolean context.  And `False` evaluates to `0` in an integer context.  We can use this to do

```
df.val.astype(bool).groupby(df.g).sum().median()

1.0
```